# How can I strip_tags except anchors with remote links?

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace, strip-tags

How can I replace contents of a tag with it's link

```
$str = 'This <strong>string</strong> contains a <a href="/local/link.html">local link</a>
        and a <a href="http://remo.te/link.com">remote link</a>';
$str = strip_tags($str,'<a>'); // strip out the <strong> tag
$str = ?????? // how can I strip out the local link anchor tag, but leave the remote link?
echo $str;
```

Desired output:

```
This string contains a local link and a <a href="http://remo.te/link.com">remote link</a>
```

Or, **better yet**, replace contents of remote link with its url:

```
This string contains a local link and a http://remo.te/link.com
```

How can I achieve the final output?

Comment: Looks like you might want to learn some regex :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard, har har. I did eventually figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace your [remotely linked anchor with the URL](http://regex101.com/r/qF9hL5):

```
<a href="(https?://[^"]+)">.*?</a>
$1
```

To remove the [anchor around a local URL](http://regex101.com/r/tD0oX8):

```
<a href="(?!https?://)[^"]+">(.*?)</a>
$1
```

---

**Explanation**:

Both expressions match `<a href="`, `">`, and `</a>` literally.  The first one will then match a remote URL (`http`, optional `s`, `://` and everything up to the closing `"`) in a capture group that we can reference with `$1`.  The second expression will match anything that does not start with the protocol used previously, and then capture the actual text of the link into `$1`.

Please note that regular expressions aren't the best solution to parsing HTML, since [HTML is not a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  However, it seems like your use case is "simple" enough that we can make a regular expression.  This ***will not*** work with links like `<a href=''></a>` or `<a href="" title=""></a>`, but it can be expanded on to allow for these use cases (hence my previous note of HTML not being regular).

---

**PHP**

```
$str = 'This <strong>string</strong> contains a <a href="/local/link.html">local link</a> and a <a href="http://remo.te/link.com">remote link</a>';
$str = strip_tags($str,'<a>');

$str = preg_replace('~<a href="(https?://[^"]+)".*?>.*?</a>~', '$1', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~<a href="(?!https?://)[^"]+">(.*?)</a>~', '$1', $str);

echo $str;
// This string contains a local link and a http://remo.te/link.com
```

Comment: Let me know if you need me to go more in depth with my expressions' explanations.

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** HTML is not a regular language and can't be realiably parsed using a regular expression. Use a DOM parser instead.

However, if you're absolutely sure of the format, you can use a regex. The whole task just needs to be split into two steps:

```
/* Replace relative URIs with their anchor text */
$str = preg_replace('#<a[^>]*href="(?=/)[^"]+">([^<]+)</a>#', '$1', $str); 

/* Replace absolute URIs with their href */
$str = preg_replace('#<a[^>]*href="((?!/)[^"]+)">[^<]+</a>#', '$1', $str);
```

Of course, this would fail if one of the attribute values contain a `>`. Using a DOM parser would be the right solution if you care about those corner cases.

Output:

```
This string contains a local link
        and a http://remo.te/link.com
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/147284)

Answer (score 1):

This is posible by using class DOMDocument

ex:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');         
$doc->loadHTML($str);
```

and further processing of links for the method:

```
$doc->getElementsByTagName('a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it:

```
$str = 'This <strong>string</strong> contains a <a href="/local/link.html">local link</a> and a <a href="http://remo.te/link.com">remote link</a>';
$str = preg_replace('/<a [^>]*?href="(http:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\\.:\/]+?)">([\\s\\S]*?)<\/a>/','\\1', $str); // strip remote links and replace with href
$str = strip_tags($str); // strip any local links
echo $str;
```

Result:

```
This string contains a local link and a http://remo.te/link.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If this string not dynamically created, and you known about data href, you can try

```
$str = 'This <strong>string</strong> contains a <a href="/local/link.html">local link</a>
        and a <a href="http://remo.te/link.com">remote link</a>';
$str = str_replace(array('<a href="/local/link.html">', '</a>'), ' ' , $str);       
$str = strip_tags($str,'<a>'); // strip out the <strong> tag
echo $str;
```

Result:

```
This string contains a  local link and a <a href="http://remo.te/link.com">remote link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple html dom might just be your best bet here:

```
$doc = str_get_html($html);

foreach($doc->find('a') as $a){
  $a->outertext = preg_match('/^http/', $a->href) ? $a->href : $a->text();
}

echo $doc;
```

Answer (score 0):

For my occasion, I needed something that replaces the anchor tag, but keeps the **link** AND the **inner text** of the anchor tag. I've therefore modified @Sam's solution and added an extra matching group for the inner text.

```
$text = strip_tags($html,'<a>');
$text = preg_replace('~<a href="(https?://[^"]+)".*?>(.*?)</a>~', '$2 ($1)', $text);
```

For `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow<a>` the above code would output `Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com)`.